# Regex - Why don't these two expressions produce the same result?

Tags: regex

I'm currently using this website to create some regular expressions for a programming language I want to build, at the moment I'm just setting up an expression for identifiers.

In my language, identifiers are expressed like most languages:

- They cannot begin with a digit, or special character other than an underscore
- After the first character they can contain alphanumeric and underscore characters

Given those rules I've come up with the following expression by myself:

```
^\D\w+$
```

Obviously, it doesn't account for special characters, however the following expression does (which I didn't make myself):

```
^(?!\d)\w+$
```

Why does the second expression account special characters? Shouldn't they be producing the same results?

Comment: `\D` contains all that is not a digit, including all that is not a word character.

Comment: Rather use `[A-Za-z]\w+` or `\p{Alpha}\w+`. As @Casimir said, `\D` contains also special characters.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte But in the first expression, this would be mean that characters such as #, %, @ etc. wouldn't be acceptable, but they are.

Comment: `\D` accepts `#` because it is not a digit. Same with the others.

Comment: You cannot expect `\w` to match "special" characters since it matches "word" chars. Read up about [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). `(?!\d)` just means the next char cannot be a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain why the second regex works.

The second regex uses a lookahead. After matching the start of the string, the engine checks whether the next character is a digit *but it does not match it*! This is important because if the next character is not a digit, it tries to use `\w` to match that same character, **which it couldn't if the character is a symbol**, if it is a digit, the negative lookahead fails and nothing is matched.

`\D` on the other hand, *will match* the character if it is not a digit, and `\w` will match whatever comes after that. That means all symbols are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This `^(?!\d)\w+$` means a string consisted of word characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` that doesn't start with a digit.

This `^\D\w+$` means a non-digit character followed by at least one character from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` set.

So `@ab01` is matched by second regex while first regex rejects it.

Answer (score 0):

`(?!\d)\w+` means "match a word which is not prepended with digits". But as you're wrapping it with `^` and `$` characters it is basically the same as just `^\w+$` which is obviously not the same as `^\D\w+$`. `^(?!\d).+\w+$` (note ".+" in the middle) would behave the same as `^\D\w+$`